# Google Home Kit - How to see data as a developer

Tags: actions-on-google

We have an app and a product that can be connected to Google Nest/Home Kit.

I want to see how many users have connected our devices to Google Home, how many commands are being executed on a daily basis and ect. Basically, I want to see some of the data. Is this possible ?

Thank you.

I searched everywhere on https://console.cloud.google.com/ , but couldn't find anything relatable.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to see helpful usage metrics about your integrations with [Google Cloud Monitoring](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring). On Google Cloud Monitoring dashboard page you can find [predefined dashboards](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/charts/predefined-dashboards) that display various charts and metrics for your integration. You also have the option for creating your own dashboard as per your requirement.